# after scrolling down recycler data getting scattered

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

in the recycle view, I'm loading data by this query it's loading fine. But after scrolling down it's getting scattered.

```
Query query = db.collection(USER_MASTER_KEY)
                .document(Uid)
                .collection("following")
                .document(xpertId)
                .collection("chat_transcript")
                .orderBy(TIMESTAMP_KEY);
```

here is my onBind method.here i'm loading image, text , video at the same time.I build this recycler in a chatting bot app.where response of the data is previously loaded in the firebase. According to the qustion the ans will be loaded.everything loading currectly but after two three video loading problem occuring.

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ChatViewHolder holder, int position) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        final ChatViewData chatViewData1 = chatViewDataList.get(position);
        klog.d("## CHAT ITEM-", new Gson().toJson(chatViewData1));
        String chatData = chatViewData1.getMsgContent();
        // If the message is still pending show placeholder
        if (chatViewData1.MSG_TYPE_PACEHOLDER.equalsIgnoreCase(chatViewData1.getMsgType())) {
            holder.gifImageViewLoading.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            holder.leftMsgTextView.setVisibility(GONE);
            holder.rightMsgTextView.setVisibility(GONE);
            holder.leftImageView.setVisibility(GONE);
            holder.relativeLayout.setVisibility(GONE);
        }

        // If the message type is blank, show nothing
        if (chatViewData1.getMsgType().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            holder.gifImageViewLoading.setVisibility(GONE);
            holder.leftMsgTextView.setVisibility(GONE);
            holder.rightMsgTextView.setVisibility(GONE);
            holder.leftImageView.setVisibility(GONE);
            holder.relativeLayout.setVisibility(GONE);
        }

        // If the message is a received message.
        if (chatViewData1.MSG_TYPE_RECEIVED.equals(chatViewData1.getMsgType())) {
            holder.leftMsgTextView.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(chatData, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
            holder.gifImageViewLoading.setVisibility(GONE);
            holder.leftMsgTextView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            //holder.chatLikeOption.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            //holder.chatDislikeOption.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            holder.rightMsgTextView.setVisibility(GONE);
            holder.leftImageView.setVisibility(GONE);
            holder.relativeLayout.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        // If the message is a sent message.
        else if (chatViewData1.MSG_TYPE_SENT.equals(chatViewData1.getMsgType())) {
            holder.rightMsgTextView.setText(HtmlCompat.fromHtml(chatData, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
            holder.gifImageViewLoading.setVisibility(GONE);
            holder.rightMsgTextView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            holder.leftMsgTextView.setVisibility(GONE);
            holder.leftImageView.setVisibility(GONE);
            holder.relativeLayout.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        // If the message is an image message.
        else if (chatViewData1.MSG_TYPE_IMAGE.equals(chatViewData1.getMsgType())) {
            //Load Image using Picasso library
            Picasso.get().load(chatViewData1.getMsgContent()).into(holder.leftImageView);
            holder.gifImageViewLoading.setVisibility(GONE);
            holder.leftImageView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            holder.rightMsgTextView.setVisibility(GONE);
            holder.leftMsgTextView.setVisibility(GONE);
            holder.relativeLayout.setVisibility(GONE);
        }
        // If the message is a video message.
        else if (chatViewData1.MSG_TYPE_VIDEO.equals(chatViewData1.getMsgType())) {
            final String videoId = chatViewData1.getMsgContent();
            final ImageView yimageView = holder.YoutubeImageView;

            final String url = "https://img.youtube.com/vi/" + videoId + "/default.jpg";
            BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions;
            bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
            Bitmap bm = loadBitmap(url, bmOptions);
            yimageView.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            //holder.videoLikeOption.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            //holder.videoDislikeOption.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
            yimageView.setImageBitmap(bm);


            yimageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent("custom-message");
                    //            intent.putExtra("quantity",Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText().toString()));
                    intent.putExtra("startTime", chatViewData1.getStartSeconds());
                    intent.putExtra("endTime", chatViewData1.getEndSeconds());
                    intent.putExtra("videoId", videoId);
                    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).sendBroadcast(intent);
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

Comment: if more information or code needed please inform me. thanks

Comment: Could you please define "it's getting scattered." ?

Comment: data rearranging itself. without any order.

Comment: How are you loading the data? Does the query return the data in the order expected?

Comment: did you try this my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this two method on adpter of recycleview

```
  @Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure the 2nd of these destroys all recycling of views!

Comment: Than what was the solutions for scattered view you know@AjahnCharles

Comment: thanks, it's working, can you tell me what was the problem @mehul chauhan